# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource with httpclient and formdata

Tags: angular, file, ionic-framework

[image]

I am new at learning web development and I think there are many questions related to my title but I did not got any satisfactory answer. I'm using Ionic 4 + Angular 5. I tried many answers but it still is not working. I'm using HttpClient with Promise to upload a video file along with its thumbnail. Please let me know what might be the issue in my case. Thanks.

```js
Request URL: https://myurl
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: 34.235.12.171:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 21 Oct 2018 06:44:54 GMT
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJwYXRtZGJpekBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1NDAxOTA2OTF9.tH6Xb9yNOS4rK4cjI_y9xrv2_o15YOSzfwDD16CiJrU
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyEQ9AIg1LzkI6FNp
Origin: http://localhost:8100
Referer: http://localhost:8100/mainpage
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
userId: izzy@gmail.com
dealId: 43627630
flLenLong: 788493
mimeType: video/mp4
tnName: thumb.png
flName: mov_bbb.mp4
tnName: (binary)
flName: (binary)
```

```css
//mainpage.page.ts

uploadFile(blob, tblob, filesize, mimeType, fFilename, token){
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.set('userId','izzy@gmail.com');
    formData.append('dealId','43627630');
    formData.append('flLenLong',filesize);
    formData.append('mimeType',mimeType);
    formData.append('tnName','thumb.png');
    formData.append('flName',fFilename);
    formData.append('tnName',tblob,'thumb.png');
    formData.append('flName', blob, fFilename);

    const url = 'deals/upfile';

    this.restService.testUpload(formData, url, token)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("uploadFile resp: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        
        
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error.status);
      });
  }
```

```html
//service.ts

testUpload(data,url,secret){
    let purl = BASE_URL+url;

    let clientheaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': secret,
    });

    return new Promise((response,error)=>{
      this.httpc.post(purl,data, {headers: clientheaders, withCredentials: true})
      .subscribe( (res) => {
        response(res);
      },(err) => {
        error(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Do you have the control over the API if yes add generic CORS policy in your API or allow only your domain

Comment: Sorry to say, I don't have the control over backend. Also I was able to use Observable with FormData without any trouble for the same API. In that there were no headers required except Authorization.

Comment: Can you post exact error which you're getting on the console while executing the request

Comment: Sure. Give me a moment.

Comment: I meant the error not the request payload

Comment: What I understand from the error message is it's the problem of cors issue.Ask the backemd team to allow your local host domain (`localhost:8100`) in the cors policy

Answer (score 0):

As a precaution to protect your users, your server must declare that it is safe for JavaScript from certain domains (or all of them) to submit data to it. Therefore your url must implement the OPTIONS HTTP method and return a permissive Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, saying that it is safe for code from certain domains to POST data to it. See the [Mozilla CORS documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for more description.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in header.

### //service.ts

```
testUpload(data,url,secret){
    let purl = BASE_URL+url;

    let clientheaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Authorization': secret,
    });

    return new Promise((response,error)=>{
      this.httpc.post(purl,data, {headers: clientheaders, withCredentials: true})
      .subscribe( (res) => {
        response(res);
      },(err) => {
        error(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

Replace `*` by actual url `http://localhost:8888`

> Note : If your server does not allow CORS, it has to be fixed in backend.

Comment: I am getting this error 'Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response' with your suggestion.

Comment: Then you will be access by some other tool like postman however it will work chrome and other browser it send the preflight request (OPTIONS) which check if the server allow the CORS. Unfortunately in your case it doesn't so better you talk to API team to your IP in whitelist.

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header needs to be sent from the server, not from the client